# From pairwise P(A > B), to P(A > all distributions in set)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$\{D_0,…,D_n\}$ is a finite collection of independent (but not necessarily identically distributed) random variables. Define $f(x,y)=P(D_x≥D_y)$ and $g(x)=P(∀y:D_x≥D_y)$. Does $f$ determine $g$, and if so how does one compute $g$ knowing $f$?

Comment: What is $D_x>D_y$ if $D_x$ and $D_y$ are distributions? (Even stranger is $P(D_x>D_y)$.)

Comment: By $P(D_x > D_y)$ I meant the probability that a random sample from $D_x$ is greater than a random sample from $D_y$. How should I represent it?

Comment: A random *sample*?? Which size? Independent from the others?

Comment: If "$P(D_x>d\mid\forall d\in D)$" means the probability that the random variable $D_x$ is larger than $D_y$ for each $y$, then it is $0$ -- because that is the probability that $D_x$ is larger than itself (being one of the random variables quantified over)!

Comment: @Did: Sorry, a random draw (so, sample of 1).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: That's true. I meant greater than all other random variables. Switching $>$ for $>=$.

Comment: So in proper probability-theoretic language, your problem is this: $\{D_0,\ldots,D_n\}$ is a finite collection of independent (but not necessarily identically distributed) _random variables_. Define $f(x,y)=\mathcal P(D_x\ge D_y)$ and $g(x)=\mathcal P(\forall y: D_x\ge D_y)$. Does $f$ determine $g$, and if so how does one compute $g$ knowing $f$?

Comment: Thanks @HenningMakholm, editing description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, knowing $f$ is not enough to determine $g$.

For a counterexample, consider these three variables:

- $D_0$ is always $0$.
- $D_1$ is either $-1$ or $1$, with a probability of $\frac12$ for each.
- $D_2$ is either $-2$ or $2$, with a probability of $\frac12$ for each.

Then we get
$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }x=y \\ 1/2 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
but $g(0)=1/4$ and $g(2)=1/2$.

So if we only know $f$, which is completely symmetric between the three variables, there is no way of knowing which of them has a $g$ of $1/4$ and which of them has a $g$ of $1/2$. (And they can be anywhere between these extremes, too).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would this still hold if we limited the distributions that the random variables come from? (ie if they followed a normal or beta distribution)

Comment: @Artur: Something like this example (though less dramatically, and it would be more difficult to compute the precise probabilities) would still hold for three normal distributions with the same mean but different standard deviations. Probably beta distributions too.